# Delete Method in Swagger mit SQLite3 und NodeJS

Tags: node.js, swagger, node-sqlite3

I have OPENAPI, which are build with Swagger. GET und POST methods works finei. but not DELETE.

index.ts
`

```
app.use("/deleteProduct/{id}", deleteProduct);
```

`delete.ts`

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { Database } from "sqlite3";
import database from "./databaseConnection";

const deleteProduct = Router()

function removeProduct(id: string, db: Database) {
  console.log(id);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    db.serialize(() => {
      db.run(`DELETE FROM product WHERE product_id = ?`, id, (err) => {
        if (err) {
          reject (err);
        }
        resolve ("Success");
      })
    })
  })
}

deleteProduct.delete("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    res.json(await removeProduct(req.params.id, database));
  }  catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error removing the product`, err.message);
  }
});

export default deleteProduct
```

`
after pressing "execute" button nothing happens..
Can someone please help me or give a hint, where a mistake can lie.

Here is a swagger.json. May there is something  wrong

```
"/deleteProduct/{id}": {
      "delete": {
        "tags": ["Delete"],
        "description": "Removes product from database",
        "produces": "application/json",
        "parameters": [
          {
            "in": "path",
            "name": "id",
            "description": "Id of the product",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
                "type": "integer"
            }
        }],
        "responses": {
          "200": {          
            "description": "Product was deleted",
            "content": {
              "application/json": {
                "schema": {
                  "type": "array"
                }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please use english when posting here so everyone can understand you.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Console tab of the browser dev tools after you click "Execute"?

Comment: No, nothing. Server antwortet with Response 200, so as if the data had been deleted. But it still stays in Databank.